# Why is the doctorReport() function not working inside the caculateBMI() function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and I was given to create a BMI app. The function doctorReport is not working. This app supposed to give BMI result and a status update to the user.
See HTML and Js below:

```
<div class="box box1"><!--box1 starts-->
          <label for="height">Height (in meters):</label><br>
          <input type="number" id="height" class="bmi-input bmi-input1" placeholder="Enter your height in meters">
          <br><br>
          <label for="weight">Weight (in kilograms):</label><br>
          <input type="number" id="weight" class="bmi-input bmi-input2" placeholder="Enter your weight in kilograms">
          <br><br>
          <button onclick="calculateBMI()" class="bmi-button">Calculate BMI</button>
          <br><br>
          <div id="result" class="bmi-result">0.00</div>
          <span class="result-unit">kg/m<sup>2</sup></span>

          <div class="doctor"></div>

        </div><!--box1 ends-->
```

```
function calculateBMI() {
    const height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    const weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    
    const bmi = weight / (height * height);
    
    const resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
    errorNotice(bmi, resultElement);
    doctorReport(height, weight);

}
//To alert user who refue to place an input
function errorNotice(bmi, resultElement) {
    if (isNaN(bmi)) {
      alert('Enter an input');
    }  
    else { 
      resultElement.innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi.toFixed(2)}`;
    }
  }

  function doctorReport(resultElement) {
    const report = resultElement.innerHTML;
    let myReport = 'Status: ';
    if (report <= 18.5) {
        myReport += 'Underweight';
    }
    else if (report > 18.5) {
        myReport += 'Healthy Weight';
    }
    else if (report > 24.9) {
        myReport += 'Over Weight';
    }
    else if (report > 30.0 || report <= 31.0) {
        myReport += 'Obesity';
    }

    else {
        myReport += 'Too Obesed, go and see a doctor';
    }
    document.getElementById('doctor').innerHTML = myReport;
  }
```

I want the status report to show in the last div with class = 'doctor' but nothing is showing. Please help.

Comment: You call `doctorReport` with a height and weight number, but your `doctorReport` expects a `resultElement` as argument.

Comment: I changed it to                                                                       
                 'doctorReport(resultElement);'                                                                
  but it did not work also

Comment: How, specifically, does it not work?  Have you taken any steps to debug it?  That's your job, not ours.

Comment: Your console should be telling you what's wrong.

Comment: I have debugged it but still can not trace it, the bug

Comment: What does your console say the error is?

Comment: Take a step back and think about what you really want to do.

Comment: Nothing just not showing anything but if i cut the function off, the remaining ones are working

Comment: There are more than one logical error.... have you used a debugger?

Comment: No just started learning Javascript

Comment: I have modified it but still not working.

Comment: Update your post to include your modifications. There should be errors in the console tab of your dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The number and type of arguments you pass to the `doctorReport` function do not correspond
- The weight limits are not compared in the right order so that if someone has an extreme BMI, it is still reported as "Healthy Weight"
- The HTML is a bit off, as the unit of measure should appear at the right side of the BMI figure.
- As the person's height is to be entered in meters, the user is expected to enter decimals. For that purpose you should not have a "step" of 1 (the default), but of 0.01. Add the `step` attribute in your HTML
- Static text like "Status: " and "Your BMI is" should not have to be put via JavaScript, but could be part of the initial HTML.
- When the user enters nothing for height, but enters a weight, the alert will not show, as the `isNaN` condition will not be true. It is better to check that *both* inputs are non-zero (after conversion to number).
- When the alert is shown, your code still continues with a call to `doctorReport`. This should not happen. I don't think that deserves a separate function anyway. Or if you feel it does, then make sure it doesn't get executed if the input is not valid.

Here is a correction:

```js
function calculateBMI() {
    const height = +document.getElementById("height").value;
    const weight = +document.getElementById("weight").value;
    const bmi = weight / (height * height);
    const resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
    const doctorElement = document.getElementById('doctor');
    
    if (!height || !weight) {
       alert('Enter an input');
    } else {
       doctorReport(resultElement, doctorElement, bmi);
    }
}

function doctorReport(resultElement, doctorElement, bmi) {
    let myReport =  bmi <= 18.5 ? 'Underweight'
                 :  bmi <= 24.9 ? 'Healthy Weight'
                 :  bmi <= 30.0 ? 'Over Weight'
                 :  bmi <= 31.0 ? 'Obesity'
                 :  'Too Obesed, go and see a doctor';
    resultElement.textContent = bmi.toFixed(2);
    doctorElement.textContent = myReport;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"><!--box1 starts-->
    <label for="height">Height (in meters):</label><br>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="height" class="bmi-input bmi-input1" placeholder="Enter your height in meters">
    <br><br>
    <label for="weight">Weight (in kilograms):</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="weight" class="bmi-input bmi-input2" placeholder="Enter your weight in kilograms">
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="calculateBMI()" class="bmi-button">Calculate BMI</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="result-unit">Your BMI is <span id="result" class="bmi-result">0.00</span> kg/m<sup>2</sup></div>
    <div>Status: <span id="doctor"></span></div>
</div><!--box1 ends-->
```

Comment: Thanks though I have corrected the error, it was from Html not js @trincot

Comment: I hope you understand that there was not just one error, and there certainly were errors in your js too, as I have pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Yes I saw the errors and have to go and read about them as a newbee. Thank you so much @trincot